# Prove that a sequence is graphical iff the sum of it is even

Tags: sequences-and-series, graph-theory

Usually a graphical sequence is defined like this :

A graphic sequence is a sequence of numbers which can be the degree sequence of some graph.

Assume that we define graphical sequence in this way :

A sequence called S is graphical iff a multigraph exists which has S as its degree sequence.

Now Prove this : 
A sequence is graphical iff the sum of it is even.

Note : I now it's simple to show this on a paper but i don't know how to write a proof. And please consider that the graph can have loops or multiple edges.

Comment: Can the graph have loops of length $1$? That is, an edge that starts and ends in the same vertex?

Comment: @Arthur yes :) it can have that kind of loop :)

Comment: As a point of interest, I've seen the term 'multigraphical' used to refer to sequences that are the degree sequence of some multigraph. Bit of a clunky word, but still..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Longrightarrow$: This is a proof you should have seen if you have done any graph theory at all. Any graphical sequence has even sum. That's because the sum of a graphical sequence is twice the number of edges in the graph.

$\Longleftarrow$: First off, since the sum of the sequence is even, there is an even number of odd terms. Pair them up two by two, and for each pair, connect the two vertices by an edge. Then fill the graph with length-$1$-loops until you're done.